# inserting data into an array field in Sequelize+Postgres

Tags: arrays, sequelize.js

I have a simple task to do: `Model.create{id_list: [1, 2, 3]}`. For some reason `id_list` is always `NULL`.

The field is defined as follows in its definition:

```
id_list: {type: DataTypes.ARRAY(DataTypes.INTEGER), defaultValue: null}
```

Note:I am able to insert/update all the other non-array fields of the Model without any problem.

Comment: Works fine for me - which version of sequelize are you on?